# How to get a custom table cell view with multiple columns and their contents

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsbuttoncell, nstablecellview

I am completely a newbie in Mac OSX development. I have a View based NSTableView with 3 columns. Here are the structures of the columns:

> ```
> TableColumn1->Table Cell View->NSImageView, NSTextField1, NSTextField2
> TableColumn2->Table Cell View->NSImageView
> TableColumn3->NSButton
> ```

I want to control the editable/hidden/etc properties of these controls. Such as, i need to hide the NSButton (regular button, not a check box or radio button) in 3rd column depending on some condition or i would need to change the text color of NSTextField2 in 1st column.

How can i do that. I've searched on Google, but didn't get any suitable solution. :(

I hope i will get the best solution here. Can anyone please help me to get out of this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are setting tag of all views that contains in cell.
first you have to find the cell

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then

```
UITextField *tempTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
tempTextField.text = @""; //what you like to change
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i am working on Mac OSX application not iOS application. :(